# Регулярное выражение для проверки регистра

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, регулярные-выражения

Хочу сделать регулярное выражение для проверки есть ли в пароле больше 2х букв верхнего регистра.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $('input[type=password]').keyup(function() {
        if ( pswd.match(/([A-Z])(?=(.*?\1){1,})/) ) {
            $("#extraCapital").removeClass('none').addClass('show');
            extraCapitalLetter = 10;
        } else {
            $("#extraCapital").removeClass('show').addClass('none');
            extraCapitalLetter = 0;
        }
    });
});
```

```css
 .extraCapital p {
    display: none;
}
.extraCapital.show p {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <label for="pswd">Пароль:</label>
                    <span><input id="pswd" type="password" name="pswd" class="password"/></span>
                    <a href="#" class="show-password" id="show-password"></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </form>
        <tr>
                    <td>Пароль содежрит больше пяти заглавных букв подряд</td>
                    <td class="extraCapital" id="extraCapital"><p>+10</p></td>
                </tr>
```

У меня пока работает с одинаковыми символами которые идут подряд. Как сделать глобальную проверку на наличие больше двух букв верхнего регистра?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте такой простой вариант:

```js
pswd.match(/[A-Z].*[A-Z].*[A-Z]/)
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, все работает!

Comment: @Lisenok Только это не самое простое выражение для движка регулярных выражений, `.*` требует большого количества шагов для поиска совпадений. Ещё оно не работает в многострочном тексте. Ещё его трудно масштабировать, если вам понадобится искать 20 повторов таких шаблонов, вам придётся написать 20 `[A-Z]`.

Comment: Мне оно нужно только для проверки пароля. Большие тексты такая регулярка вычислять не будет. Но спасибо за пояснение!
Вы бы не могли обьяснить почему конструкция /[A-Z]{2,}/ работает только если буквы верхнего регистра идут подряд?

Comment: Да, я исходил из того, что проверяться будет только короткий однострочный текст и имел в виду — простое для восприятия тому, кто ещё не много знает о регулярных выражениях.

Comment: `[A-Z]{2,}` — служебный символ `{2,}` как раз и означает: от двух и больше предыдущих символов подряд. Поэтому, чтобы символы искались и подряд, и не подряд, мы вставляем между ними `.*` — то есть "0 или больше любых символов"